# Use ChoiceDialog to assign value to a variable within a function

Tags: variable-definitions, dialog-window

This may be a routine answer that I have overlooked, but I am stumped...

If I want to write a function using ChoiceDialog, how can I use what ChoiceDialog returns (true or false) to either set a variable to True or False(or perhaps to either create a global variable or not create a global variable which would effectively do the same thing for my purposes). Is it possible to use the returned True or False within the same function to create this global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`ChoiceDialog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChoiceDialog.html) returns a value, as opposed to just printing something, you are free to use it as the right hand side of a variable assignment.  Here is a simple example of a function that calls `ChoiceDialog` and assigns the `True` or `False` to a local variable.

```
choice[] := Module[{val}, 
   val = ChoiceDialog["choose"]; 
   If[val, a, b] 
]
```

[image]